# Flow type Generic types

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I am trying to make a configurable type as follows:

```
import * as React from 'react';

type Identity<T: {}> = {
    data: {
        refetch: void => void,
        T: {}
    }
};

({ data }: Identity<{foo: string }>) => <div>{data.foo}</div>;
```

But I am getting:

`Cannot get data.foo because property foo is missing in object type [1].`

Am I missing something obvious? This is the shape of graphql hoc return data.

Thank you

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdMAnmFnAJIAmWAdjMMwA8AFQBccAN4BfAHxwAvJLpwVcTshjJxE5ar1jJU3SqNT6cOgAoJajcjhTxXXvyESCECONQwowHgDmDjIAlApygpzAAG4yEuqaAHQeEFKCAPRRsfRAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
type RefetchObj = {
    refetch: void => void,
}
type Identity<T: {}> = {
    data: T & RefetchObj
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. next to data I am going to return more keys. I will update the question

Comment: @Adam It's a bit unclear from the question what you'd like the types to look like. Are you saying there's both the `refetch` function _and_ the properties from `T` in `data`? That would be `data: T & { refetch: void => void }`.

Comment: @noppa I just saw your comment. Your answer is exactly what I was looking for! If you put it as an answer I will accept it. Thank you

Comment: @Adam I replied here because Evert's answer was so close already, it just missed the final `"next to data I am going to return more keys"` part. Now that the answer has been edited to reflect that, IMO you can just accept this one.

Comment: Glad I could help :)